# VScode persistent sessions (restored terminals after vscode restarts) are not working reliably

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-tasks

I found that persistent sessions does not always works on VScode and almost always not working on remote WSL VScode instance.

the setting docs also states "Time to persist the session during shutdown is limited, so it may be aborted when using high-latency remote connections.", which explains why remote WSL terminals almost never restored.

the ability to save the terminals are crucial to my work, and i don't actually need the session history but the terminals to open in their last working directory(similar to how it perfectly works on WebStorm).

I don't want to configure tasks for workspace or using 'Terminals Manager'(which do the same as tasks), I just want terminals instances to be re-opened in their last working directory reliably. (I'm working with big monorepo and 'reliably' is crucial)

so, is there a way to at least re-open the terminals in their last working directory with their name and color saved (without sessions command history)?